# Can anyone tell me the logical difference between the mentioned codes

Tags: c, algorithm

I am unable to figure out the why my code is not able to satisfy a test case for the question while editorial's code is working fine.

---

**Question:**

You are in an infinite 2D grid where you can move in any of the 8 directions :

```
(x, y) to

(x+1, y), 
(x-1, y), 
(x, y+1), 
(x, y-1), 
(x-1, y-1), 
(x+1, y+1), 
(x-1, y+1), 
(x+1, y-1)
```

You are given a sequence of points and the order in which you need to cover the points. Give the minimum number of steps by which you can achieve it. You start from the first point.

---

**Input:**

Given two integer arrays `A` and `B`, where `A[i]` is `x coordinate` and `B[i]` is `y coordinate` of the ith point, respectively.

**Output:**

Return an Integer, (i.e minimum number of steps).

**Example:**

```
Input : [(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
Output : 2
```

It takes one step to move from `(0, 0) to (1, 1)`. It takes one more step to move from `(1, 1) to (1, 2)`.

---

**my code:-**

```
int coverPoints(int *A, int n1, int *B, int n2) {
    int count = 0, ele1 = 0, ele2 = 0, i;

    for (i = 0; i < n1 - 1; i++) {
        ele1 = abs(A[i+1] - A[i]);
        ele2 = abs(B[i+1] - A[i]);
        if (ele1 > ele2) {
            count += ele1;
        } else {
            count += ele2;    
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

**editorial solution:-**

```
int coverPoints(int *X, int n1, int *Y, int n2) {
    int stepsx = 0, stepsy = 0, diffx = 0, diffy = 0, steps = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < (n1-1); i++) {
        diffx = X[i+1] - X[i];
        if (diffx < 0)
            diffx = diffx * (-1);
        //stepsx = stepsx + diffx;

        diffy = Y[i+1] - Y[i];
        if (diffy < 0)
            diffy = diffy * (-1);
        //stepsy = stepsy + diffy;

        if (diffx > diffy)
            steps = steps + diffx;
        else
            steps = steps + diffy;
    }

    return steps;
}
```

**The test case that is not working is: -**

```
A : [ 4, 8, -7, -5, -13, 9, -7, 8 ]
B : [ 4, -15, -10, -3, -13, 12, 8, -8 ]

expected output = 108
my output = 105
```

Comment: Seems the same to me. Are these giving different results? (I mean, have you tried the "editorial" solution?)

Comment: yes i did ,editorial solution is working fine

Comment: Then step over both and see where the deviation is.

Comment: @Student: good editing effort!

Comment: You will also need to protect your array bound with the lesser of `n1` or `n2`, e.g. `for (i = 0; i < (n1 < n2 ? n1 : n2) - 1; i++)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In this circumstance, I think ```coverPoints``` expect n1 equal n2. Imagine a coordinate on 2D surface which only has x or y, it shouldn't happen. ```coverPoints``` could either have 1 argument ```n``` replace ```n1``` and ```n2```, or add an assertion that ```n1 == n2```.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu, I agree -- `n1` should be equal to `n2`, but as written, there is no validation. The ternary insures that the lesser of either `n1` or `n2` is used to iterate over the arrays to prevent reading beyond the bounds of one if they differ in size. You can also, just check `n1 == n2` or handle the error. Either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem in this line

```
ele2 = abs(B[i+1]-A[i]);

diffy = Y[i+1] - Y[i];
```

it will be :

```
ele2 = abs(B[i+1]-B[i]);
```

Comment: @EugeneSh. tnx.

Answer (score 1):

There is a copy+paste typo in `ele2 = abs(B[i+1] - A[i]);`. The code should be:

```
ele2 = abs(B[i+1] - B[i]);
```